# Transaction not rolling back

Tags: spring, sql-server-2008, transactions, mybatis, fuseesb

I have mybatis 3.0.4 with mybatis-spring integration 1.0.1 deployed within Fuse (OSGi). I've created a basic database within SQLServer 2008. In Spring I've configured a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` data source and a `DataSourceTransactionManager` transaction manager.

Now I've created my own bundle to be deployed within Fuse which inserts some rows into the database. I've told the bundle to use the configured data source and transaction manager. The method which carries out the logic looks like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void go(RecsCashContext context) throws ActionException {
```

When this method throws an exception I can follow Spring through seeing the expected behaviour triggered. This leads me to Springs `JtaTransactionManager` and `doRollBack(..)`.

So everything looks promising, except that when I look at the database, sure enough it's in an unstable state as previous inserts have not been roll back.

I'm at a loss on this one and I'm struggling to find any information online. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out Fuse (servicemix) already exposes a transaction manager via an OSGi service within bundle `org.apache.aries.transaction.manager_0.2.0.incubating [49]`. As a result when I was looking up the transaction manager service, the one exposed by bundle 49 got picked up first.

This was resolved by clearly specifying the transaction manager I was interested in. At the moment I am doing this using the bean-name propery:

```
<osgi:reference id="transactionManager" bean-name="transactionManager" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager" />
```

Though this could also be done by using a filter, but preferably we'll just make use of the transaction manager service that's already being expose as opposed to providing our own.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of exception is being thrown? Unless you tell Spring to explicitly rollback when a particular exception is thrown, it will proceed. By default, Spring's transaction handling only rolls back when an unchecked exception (e.g. RuntimeException) is thrown. In your case, if you're expecting the rollback to occur when ActionException occurs, you're out of luck unless you make the following modification:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={ActionException.class})
public void go(RecsCashContext context) throws ActionException {
```

More details are in [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html), specifically in section 10.5.6.1, @Transactional settings

Comment: In this scenario I am actually forcing a runtime exception with the purpose of testing the transactionality. As I mentioned I am able to follow through the Spring source to see it assert that roll back is valid.

Comment: Is all of your persistence work being done within the go(...) method, or are some of the inserts being done in another method with a different propagation rule?

Comment: All in the same... my concern is that perhaps mybatis is creating new transactions for each insert it propagates - though I can see why it would do this.

Comment: Have you tried using different transaction managers? You say you're using a JtaTransactionManager; maybe try the DatasourceTransactionManager? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your input Filip, I've now identified the issue as I've detailed below.

Comment: Looks good. You can mark your own answer as accepted, as it will help others who might face a similar problem.